# MySQL - retrieving a HTML Table from the database - backslashes before quotation symbol

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add a html table into a text field in a MySQL database. Retrieving the data is not a problem it is the way the data is returned. Wherever there is quotation marks "" a backslash is added before it, how do i stop this/ rectify it?

example of what i mean:

```
<tr>
<td style="background:#bfd; color:black; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;">Win</td>
<td align="center">15–1</td>
<td><a href="#" title="Frank Mir">Frank Mir</a></td>
<td>TKO (punches)</td>
<td>UFC 146</td>
<td align="center">2</td>
<td align="center">3:04</td>
</tr>
```

This then returns:

```
<tr>
<td style=\"background:#bfd; color:black; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;\">Win</td>
<td align=\"center\">15–1</td>
<td><a href=\"#\" title=\"Frank Mir\">Frank Mir</a></td>
<td>TKO (punches)</td>
<td>UFC 146</td>
<td align=\"center\">2</td>
<td align=\"center\">3:04</td>
</tr>
```

any help greatly appreciated :D

Comment: What driver/language you are using?

Comment: html and php...I have the data already in the database it's just the way it is returning it with the backslash making none of the CSS work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the PHP manual for

- [mysql-real-escape-string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)
- [function.stripslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)