# How to save HTML in database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have some question about saving html code in mysql database
every time when I put the charter " ' " in the database it changes to " / ".

Example:
somthing like that

```
<p>That's my name</p>
```

After saving it look like this:

```
<p>That\'s my name</p>
```

what can i do?
thank u all

Comment: How are you "putting it in the database"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848146/mysql-retrieving-a-html-table-from-the-database-backslashes-before-quotation

Comment: no need to do something, when you retrieve this string from DB it will show as it is.

Comment: why do you need to save an `html` tag to db?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Use [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/19068) to escape data going into the database
- Use nothing else to escape data going into the database (otherwise you will double escape which can use this problem)

  - Do not use `mysql_real_escape_string`
  - Do not use `addslashes`
  - etc
- Do not escape data coming *out* of the database (since that will cause this problem)
- Make sure [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) are disabled (since having them turned on will escape data going into and out of the database and cause this problem).

Answer (score 2):

You are using addslashes like escape functions in your code.

`addslashes()` — Quote string with slashes - http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

`stripslashes()` — Un-quotes a quoted string - http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Answer (score 0):

Use [stripslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to remove '\' from HTML data. Actually (') is used define string in MySql, so it ecaspe it (by putting \ in-front) in order to avoid any unintentional use.